# Counting total rows in query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, ibatis

I have a SqlServer `SELECT`

```
DECLARE @offset INT;
DECLARE @limit INT;

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT t.*,
                Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS RowNum
         FROM   (SELECT *
                 FROM   Table1
                 UNION
                 SELECT *
                 FROM   Table2) t)
SELECT *
FROM   cte
WHERE  RowNum BETWEEN @offset AND @offset + @limit
```

How can I know the total of rows limited without the WHERE condition `RowNum BETWEEN @offset AND @offset + @limit`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might add count(*) over() to cte:

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT t.*,
                Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS RowNum,
                count(*) over() as Cnt
         FROM   (SELECT *
                 FROM   Table1
                 UNION
                 SELECT *
                 FROM   Table2) t)
SELECT *
FROM   cte
WHERE  RowNum BETWEEN @offset AND @offset + @limit
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the inverse row trick

```
Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Id asc) AS RowNum,
Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Id desc) AS InverseRowNum,
```

then (RowNum + InverseRowNum) - 1 = total rows

Answer (score 0):

Treat the count of the result as another CTE, and return it alone with the record set. Not perfect but should match what you want.

```
DECLARE @offset INT;
DECLARE @limit INT;

;WITH cte
 AS (SELECT t.*,
            Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS RowNum
     FROM   (SELECT *
             FROM   Table1
             UNION
             SELECT *
             FROM   Table2) t)
, total_cte as (
       select count(1) total_count from cte
)
SELECT cte.*, total_count
FROM   cte, total_cte
WHERE  RowNum BETWEEN @offset AND @offset + @limit
```