# Possible to return records and count from a CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

Say I have a stored proc that has a return param called `Count` and it is made up of the following SQL:

```
with temp as
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY o.createDate) as rowNum,
           o.orderId
    FROM Orders as o

)
SELECT * FROM temp where rowNum BETWEEEN 10 and 20
SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM Temp
```

Currently this will break because `Temp` is gone after the first select.  Is it possible for me to set the value of the return parameter to the total number of rows in my CTE **and** return the rows  from 10-20?

I'm thinking I might have to do this using a temp table but I'm curious if it can be done using a CTE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting total rows in query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997171/counting-total-rows-in-query)

Comment: Actually maybe not as that returns an extra column rather than being something for an output param.

Comment: Yeah no dice.  Temp table might be my best bet?

Comment: Potentially... you could change: `SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM Temp` to `SELECT @Count = @@ROWCOUNT`?

Comment: @malk that would just return info about the 10 rows selected not the total that would be returned unfiltered. Sometimes 2 separate queries can work out better. There is an article by Paul White on Sql Server Central looking at pagination that tests various approaches.

Comment: Haha right. I suppose you would already know 20-10. I have never found a way to chain queries on a CTE and am interested if you find a solution. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do what you are trying to do. Gordon's answer is acceptable except that it isn't returning a value to your variable.

You are running into a fundamental problem. CTEs only allow for one query after it.

A temp table or table variable would be the only way to go. Unless you would would go after the table again outside of the CTE to return the variable, like this:

```
with temp as
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY o.createDate) as rowNum,
           o.orderId
    FROM Orders as o
)
SELECT * FROM temp where rowNum BETWEEEN 10 and 20
SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM Orders
```

Answer (score 4):

You could put the value directly into temp:

```
with temp as
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY o.createDate) as rowNum,
           count(*) over () as cnt,
           o.orderId
    FROM Orders as o

)
SELECT * FROM temp where rowNum BETWEEEN 10 and 20
```

You can then read the cnt with every row.